# How to sort strings by number of occurrences with bash in linux?

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, text-processing

I have a file that contains lines like this:

```
May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.2
May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.1
May 25 05:34:16 192.0.1.5
May 25 05:38:16 192.0.2.2
```

Now i want to get the number of occurrences of the IPs and list them by most occurred and also how often they appeared, like this:

```
2 May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.2
1 May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.1
1 May 25 05:34:16 192.0.1.5
```

Preferably a one liner in bash with awk.

Comment: The top 3 ways to discourage people from helping you are: 1) just saying "it doesn't work", 2) not showing any effort yourself, and 3) asking for a one-liner. You hit 2 out of 3 so YMMV. You might want to read [ask] and then try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU sort and GNU uniq:

```
sort -k4 file | uniq --count --skip-fields=3
```

Output:

```
      1 May 25 05:34:16 192.0.1.5
      1 May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.1
      2 May 25 05:34:16 192.0.2.2
```

---

See: `man uniq`

Comment: didn't knew about `--skip-fields` , into my notes.